# instead of two colour graph only one color graph is showing up. in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If you run this code you will understand my problem. I want to see both red and yellow graph based on the value in z list but. only one color is showing up for all dots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use("ggplot")
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15]
y = [6,5,7,2,9,8,3,4,1,10,15]
z = [1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1]
x_vals = []
y_vals = []
z_vals = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)

def animate(i,x_vals,y_vals,z_vals):
    print("i:",i)
    x_vals.append(x[i])
    y_vals.append(y[i])
    z_vals.append(z[i])
    ax1.clear()
    if z_vals[i] == 1:
        l1, = ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'ro')
    if z_vals[i] == 2:
        l2, = ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'yo')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x')
    plt.xticks(x_vals, x_vals)

print("Animedotted")
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals), interval=1000, blit = False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want dots of both colors at each iteration ?

in your `animate` function, you do a `ax.clear`, so at each iteration all dots are removed.

Also,

```
if z_vals[i] == 1:
    l1, = ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'ro')
if z_vals[i] == 2:
    l2, = ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'yo')
```

makes it that you can only have one color.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: You need to be clearer on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to have red dot when z contains 1 and yellow dot when it's 2.

Comment: when I run your code I get red for the first 2 iterations, then yellow, and so on.

Comment: I really don't understand your issue. When I run your code I only get one color per iteration.

Comment: what more you want to understand. You can ask.